# Combine multiple re.sub into one

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to remove spaces before and after '|' in a string.

This works:

```
s = 'cat |  purr | dog       |woof| cow|   moo'
a = re.sub('\s+\|', '|', s).strip()
b= re.sub('\|\s+', '|', a)
print(b)
    
cat|purr|dog|woof|cow|moo
```

I am trying to combine the two re.sub into one like this and result is not correct:

```
b = re.sub("(\s+\||\|\s+)", '|', s).strip()
print(b)

cat|  purr| dog|woof|cow|moo
```

Can someone help me with this?

P.S: I have tried using the split() function to separate the fields with '|' as the delimiter and then applying strip() function to each field and then assembling the string again. It works but seems tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `*` quantifier for spaces to match zero or more space in one go.

```
print(re.sub('\s*\|\s*', '|', s))

# cat|purr|dog|woof|cow|moo
```

But for the case simple like this, a normal string replacement would do the job too.

```
print(s.replace(' ', '').replace('\t', ''))
# cat|purr|dog|woof|cow|moo
```

Comment: Regular expression worked. Thanks. The simple replace will remove spaced inside the string as well (I need 'd    og' to remain as 'd    og'. Only the spaces before or after '|' needed to be trimmed.